# How to show the following function is surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Question:

> Consider the function $f:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ defined by  $$f(x)= \begin{pmatrix} 1&1&2\\ -1&1&0\\ \end{pmatrix}x$$
>   Show the function is surjective.

How can I show?

Comment: You've written the definition of injective.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You are right.

Comment: Do you have solution ideas?

Comment: This function is not injective. Try $x_1=(1,1,0)$ and $x_2=(0,0,1)$.

Comment: Very thanks. And how can we show it is surjective?

Comment: Try to find $x$ such that $f(x)$ is equal to $(1,0)$. Then do the same for $(0,1)$. Then use linearity to conclude for general $(a,b)$ in the codomain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
f\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
f\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$
Note then that the vectors $\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$ and
$\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ are linearly independent.

How do I know they are and what columns of the matrix should be considered? Do Gaussian elimination:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&2\\ -1&1&0\\ \end{pmatrix}
\to
\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&2\\ 0&2&2\\ \end{pmatrix}
\qquad R_2\gets R_2+R_1
$$
The pivots are in columns 1 and 2, so the matrix has rank $2$ and a set of generators of the image is the first and second column; but rank $2$ already tells you the map is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Write $x = (x^1, x^2, x^3) \in \mathbb R^3$ and let any $y=(y^1,y^2) \in \mathbb R^2$ be given. The what can you say about the solutions of the following system?

$$\begin{cases}x^1 + x^2 + 2x^3 &= y^1\\-x^1 + x^2 &= y^2 \end{cases}$$

Notice that $1 \cdot 1 + 1\cdot 1 \neq 0$ ($a_1b_2- a_2b_1$), so what can you say about the configuration of those planes? What is their intersection?